# PowerQUICC Instructions and Basic C++ Memory allocation

Tags: c++, linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

Suppose I have an array of char, like:

```
char test[5] = {'t','e','s','t','\0'};
```

Someone told me that on a Windows 32-bit system, 32 bits will always be allocated, due to how memory is managed. I don't believe this, but in any case, does anyone know how memory is typically managed in embedded systems that use the PowerQuicc II processor where the C++ application in question is running on a 32-bit instance of Linux, where there is typically only 32 megabytes of flash/storage memory, and 32 megabytes of dynamic memory? Would the C-string shown above really use 4 bytes (32 bits), or would the memory be 'packed' together with other small allocations, as the data is sent along the main bus for data-processing?

Comment: How array of 5 characters may fit into 4 bytes? It will occupy at least 5 bytes. Additional size depends only from the alignment of the next variable in the same section. Or, if this is the last variable in the section, additional size depends on alignment of the next section.

Comment: Pardon my mistake, I should have asked if 'test' would occupy 5 bytes, or 32 bytes.  I get that it would occupy at least 5 bytes, but I don't understand the concept of byte alignment. Can you elaborate on this 'byte alignment' concept?

Comment: If your `test` variable is the first variable in the section and starts, e.g. at address 0x81001000, than it will occupy bytes from 0x81001000 till 0x81001005. If **next** variable, say `a`, has alignment 16, then it cannot start at address 0x81001005 (this address doesn't have given alignment). Instead, variable `a` will starts from address 0x81001010, so bytes from 0x81001005 till 0x81001010 will be lost, **as if** your `test` variable will occupy 16 bytes instead of 5. (I use alignment 16 bytes in example, because alignment 32 bytes is unusual in practice).

Comment: Would a 32-bit Linux OS typically use a 16 byte alignment?

Comment: It depends from exact architecture. While alignment for native integer on 32-bit OS is 4 byte(usually), some other types may require additional alignment. E.g., *float* and *64-bit integer* may require 8 byte alignment, parameters for *vector instructions*, where operand's size is 128 bit, may require to be aligned on 16 bytes.

Comment: Thanks. I will do some more studying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128047/discussion-between-matt-fomich-and-tsyvarev).